# Show edges only on hover

Tags: javascript, graph-visualization, sigma.js

I exported to a Sigma.js template from Gephi. I want the edges to be shown only when you hover over the node. I added this in `network/config.json` but it is not helping:

```
  "drawingProperties": {
  **"drawEdges": false,**
  "defaultEdgeType": "curve",
  "defaultHoverLabelBGColor": "#002147",
  "defaultLabelBGColor": "#ddd",
  "activeFontStyle": "bold",
  "defaultLabelColor": "#000",
  "labelThreshold": 10,
  "defaultLabelHoverColor": "#fff",
  "fontStyle": "bold",
  "hoverFontStyle": "bold",
  "defaultLabelSize": 14
}
```

`network/js/main.js` :

```
var a = sigma.init(document.getElementById("sigma-canvas")).drawingProperties(drawProps).graphProperties(graphProps).mouseProperties(mouseProps);
```

PS: I don't know javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it

```
configProps={
drawEdges: false
};

var a = sigma.init(document.getElementById("sigma-canvas")).drawingProperties(drawProps).graphProperties(graphProps).mouseProperties(mouseProps).configProperties(configProps);
```

PS: I know nothing about js